# Why is that my android app crashes whenever I use an object of FileInputStream class in methods of Apache poi/tika?

Tags: android, apache, apache-poi, fileinputstream, apache-tika

Here is my code. I have checked my execution at each step and the parses.parse method is what causing the problem?

```
 Uri u = data.getData();
        String str = u.getPath();
        File file = new File(str);

        try
        {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            BodyContentHandler bodyContentHandler = new BodyContentHandler();
            Metadata metdata = new Metadata();
            ParseContext pContext = new ParseContext();
            OOXMLParser parser = new OOXMLParser();

            parser.parse(fileInputStream, bodyContentHandler, metdata, pContext);
            Toast.makeText(this, bodyContentHandler.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show where `data` is coming from. Most likely, `data.getData()` is not a `file` `Uri`.